# Como declarar um modulo .xlsx que o typescript entenda?

Tags: typescript

Adicionei nos assets um arquivo que será usado de modelo para ser baixado no HTML através da tag . Ao eu importar isso num arquivo JSX, ele retorna esse erro de typescript:

> Cannot find module '@/assets/docs/tesxt.xlsx' or its corresponding
> type declarations.

Print:

[image: Erro do Erro]

Tentei mexer em algumas configurações no tsconfig.json, e criar algum arquivo para declarar módulos .xlsx na raiz do projeto (app.d.ts). Mas nada funcionou até o momento.

A ideia seria consertar isso pro typescript reconhecer meu arquivo.

Comment: cria um arquivo `xlxs.d.ts` dentro de `src/@types` e adiciona `declare module '*.xlsx'`. No tsconfig, adicione `"typeRoots": ["./src/@types"]`.

Comment: Isso resolveu, obrigado ;)

Comment: bom que ajudou Arthur. quando for adicionar arquivo .png, .svg dentre outros pode fazer isso. vou melhorar sua pergunta.